# Как правильно оформить недосказанное название фильма?

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика, кавычки, многоточие

Есть пример, в котором говорящий не с первого раза произносит название фильма, пытаясь вспомнить, как оно звучит. Правильно ли оформлять такие случаи подобным образом?

*Фильм "Как приру"... "Как приручить драко"... "Как приручить дракона" мне понравился.*

Comment: Такое нельзя оформить из-за необходимости удваивать многоточия.

Answer (score 4):

"Как приручить дракона" — это полное название фильма, поэтому при его обрыве многоточие в обязательном порядке необходимо **внутри** кавычек.

Если предполагается заминка в речи, то по правилам многоточие нужно и после кавычек. Получается вот такая "сильно многоточечная" конструкция.
*— Фильм «Как приру...»... «Как приручить драко...»... «Как приручить дракона» мне понравился.*

Если же предположить, что и так понятна прерывистость речи (ведь название фильма произносится не полностью), то в отсутствие второго многоточия получится предложение со стыковкой кавычек. Это тоже не есть хорошо.
*— Фильм «Как приру...» «Как приручить драко...» «Как приручить дракона» мне понравился.*

А вообще... Предложение мне кажется  искусственным, неживым каким-то.
В реплике можно показать эмоции (и неуверенность, и радость вспоминания), обыграть их. Одновременно можно избавиться и от спорных моментов. Например:
*— Что вчера смотрел?

— Фильм... «Как приру...» или «Как приро...»? Вспомнил — «Как приручить дракона»! Мне понравился.*

Думаю, что теоретически возможен контекст, в котором без двух многоточий не обойтись.
— Тебя нет уже два дня! Что-то случилось?
— Болею... Пытаюсь читать «А зори здесь тихие...»... Скучаю...

Comment: Хотел об этом написать, но побоялся критики (с двумя многоточиями нелепо получается). Заминка в речи же одна, но из-за кавычек многоточие надо удвоить. Лайк.

Comment: Не ожидала, честное слово. Семь потов сошло, пока дождалась от Вас похвалы. Спа-а-сибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы оформил так:
Фильм "Как приру..."/"Как приручить драко..."/"Как приручить дракона" мне понравился.

Comment: Проблема в том, что слеш означает "или".