Нужен ли какой-либо знак между двумя цитатами?
автор замечает: "Каков же был тогда пруд!..." _ "... русалкам нравились мои цветы"

Надо, думаю, привести полную цитату. Тогда можно и порассуждать о расстановке знаков.

@РиммаМихайлова, допустим, в сочинении используешь неполные две цитаты, тогда как? именно в той форме, которая представлена у меня в вопросе

Вопрос к участнику, поставившему "минус" вопросу. А вы часто видели такую конструкцию, где встречаются, "сталкиваются", можно сказать наползают друг на друга, два троеточия? А ведь в правилах таких объяснений нет. Надо самому крутить-вертеть. Вот подобное: (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472291/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0).

В качестве варианта:
Автор замечает: "Каков же был тогда пруд!..  русалкам нравились мои цветы".
Пояснение

Принцип конструирования текста из отдельных цитат таков: мы считаем подлинные выражения членами предложения, которые отличаются от других членов только наличием кавычек.

Если цитаты идут одна за другой, то достаточно общих кавычек, то есть не имеет смысла ставить кавычки два раза. Одни кавычки обозначают дословное цитирование.

А если мы используем только одни кавычки, то не стоит также использовать два многоточия. Иначе трудно понять, зачем они там нужны.


Представим себе это предложение без обозначения дословности высказывания. И тогда возникает вопрос: зачем ставить два многоточия подряд, что это за знак такой? Где-нибудь в примерах из литературы такое можно увидеть?
Розенталь,  § 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора
Примечание. Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в 
текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются 
кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится: Это «не 
хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); Предположение 
дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в 
избе», всё больше собирало сторонников (Ф.); Он вспомнил 
пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не 
поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком 
«Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.


между цитатами, которые перечисляются, мы ставим запятую. а что делать с теми цитатами, которые окончиваются восклицательным/вопросительным знаком?

Можно использовать две отдельные цитаты (самый простой вариант). Автор замечает: «Каков же был тогда пруд!», «...русалкам нравились мои цветы". Розенталь: Не говорить же: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!» — две реплики, разделенные неповторяющимся союзом или; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159 В кавыках можно использовать прописную или строчную букву, а также многоточие.  Также: Мы прочитали надписи на камне: «Навек с тобой», «Здесь были Коля с Катей».

Но можно использовать цитаты при построении предложения, тогда достаточно одних кавычек. (Надо представить, что вы не цитируете, а сами пишете это предложение.) Лучше всего обозначить многоточием прерывистую речь (отдельные мысли разделены паузами). Тогда восклицательный знак впишется в такое оформление, а также цитаты будут разделены между собой (сплошной текст из них некорректно составлять).

Перенесу ваше предложение в ответ (так проще и нагляднее разбираться).
автор замечает: "Каков же был тогда пруд!..." _ "... русалкам нравились мои цветы"
• Предложение надо начинать с прописной буквы.
Автор замечает...
• Используется только одна пара кавычек, в конце предложения ставится точка.
• После восклицательного или вопросительного знака максимально может быть только две точки (не три).
Каков же был тогда пруд!..
Пример:
Все расписавшись? Ну, теперь глядите!.. Раз... два... три!!. (А. П. Чехов. Маска).
• Многоточие от следующего за ним слова пробелом не отделяется (...русалкам).
● Если ничего не перестраивать, то окончательно получаем предложение, в котором нужны два многоточия подряд.
Автор замечает: "Каков же был тогда пруд!.. ...Русалкам нравились мои цветы".
Знаки препинания при цитатах (ПАС)
✦ Дополнительная информация о двух многоточиях (01.07.2024)
Из справочника А. Э. Мильчина и Л. К. Чельцовой (8.5.2. Сочетание многоточия с другими знаками препинания):

В источнике:
Мы вышли из сакли. Вопреки предсказанию моего спутника, погода прояснилась...
В цитате:
«Мы вышли из сакли. ...Погода прояснилась...»
«Мы вышли... ...Погода прояснилась...»

